Transpose with flexible range based on input in a cell



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G




1

Q1
Q2
Q3
Q4

Product A


2
Product A
500
900

100




3
Product B
600

400


500


4
Product C
100

350
785

900


5
Product D
230
600
210
690

100


6
Product E
310
900
480
125




7











In Range G3:G6 I want to transpose the values based on the row criteria entered in Cell G1. 
(Note: Products listed in Column A are always unique.)
In this example the Row B2:E2 for Product A is transposed an displayed in Range G3:G6.
So far I have been able to develop this formula:
=LET(
a,TRANSPOSE(B2:E2),
IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(a,a<>0),SEQUENCE(4,,1)),""))

This formula works. 
However, I have no clue how to make the Range B2:E2 in this formula flexible so it changes based on the input in Cell G1.
Do you have any idea how to modify it to make it work?

Another solution where you pass the whole data range to the data variable:
=LET(data,A2:E6,
    Product,G1,
    TOCOL(FILTER(DROP(data,,1),CHOOSECOLS(data,1)=Product,"no result"),1))


It would be appreciated to add if_empty to FILTER. Not having it the formula can result "#CALC!" which is not so informational instead of "#N/A".

@rotabor: you are absolutly right - updated the answer

Another solution (simpler and better performance) can be:
=TOCOL(XLOOKUP(G1,A2:A6,B2:E6),1)



It's a nice solution provider the values in column A are unique. Else @Ike's tocol/filter version is a better choice.

@P.b I guess Ike's solution can solve another task since duplication of a product in this task is not expected.

=LET(a,FILTER(B2:E6,A2:A6=G1),TRANSPOSE(FILTER(a,a<>0)))

Result:

Or =TOCOL(FILTER(B2:E6,A2:A6=G1),3) if you have Excel 365

Another option using FILTER().
=TOCOL(FILTER(B2:E6,A2:A6=G1),1)



Because every problem deserves a solution which is overly complex and over-engineered:
=LET(
    product, J2,
    dataRange, B3:F7,
    productRow, XLOOKUP(product, INDEX(dataRange,,1), ROW(dataRange)-MIN(ROW(dataRange))+1),
    valuesRange, INDEX(dataRange, productRow, 2):INDEX(dataRange, productRow, 5),
    filteredValues, TRANSPOSE(FILTER(valuesRange, valuesRange<>0)),
    IFERROR(INDEX(filteredValues, SEQUENCE(4,,1)), "")
)



Thanks Michal, but XMATCH is feeling left out ;)
=TOCOL(INDEX(B2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, E:E <> "", E:E, , , -1), 
XMATCH(G1, A2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, A:A <> "", A:A, , , -1)), ), 1)

Or, courtesy of rotabor, (accommodating for future entries with start:XLOOKUP(TRUE, column <> ""):
=TOCOL(XLOOKUP(G1,  
A2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, A:A <> "", A:A, , , -1),  
B2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, E:E <> "", E:E, , , -1)), 1)



Simplifying the formula step by step, you finally should get =TOCOL(XLOOKUP(G1,A2:A6,B2:E6),1)
